# ODBC Data Source Driver 'Does Not Exist' After Updating to Windows 10

Tags: drivers, windows-10, microsoft-access, database, odbc

I received the following errors in the Microsoft ODBC Data Source manager (64-bit), for my data source an MS Access DB (.accdb), after updating to Windows 10 from 7 and uninstalling MS 2010 and installing 2013:

"The driver of this User DSN does not exist. It can only be removed."

[image]

And also:
"The driver of this 64-bit System DSN does not exist. It can only be removed."

There doesn't seem to be any results when searching for the error for this online (other than one result with DLL info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely that I uninstalled the MS database drivers when I uninstalled the older version of Office (and not related to the recent Windows update) and the new one must not come with the drivers as standard.

The drivers I needed were within the 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable' that is currently available at the following address:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: This is possibly an issue specific to Office 365 ("click to run") installations: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2874601. A similar issue may be caused by 64-bit/32-bit incompatibility: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cfba334b-b990-4032-98c2-f694af52f37c/office-2013-64-bits-odbc-drivers?forum=officeitpro.